# How can I create an view like an lollipop task manager of top to bottom swipe?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create an app that will show information like notepad that will be able to swipe from top to bottom like an lollipop task manager.

How can I able to do like the attached screenshot image.

Please help me.

[image]